# Genesis change page slug posts pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, slug, posts, genesis

I'm using Wordpress - Genesis and as Childtheme Enterprise Pro. I love them both but I have one question about pagination slug.

On this page it now is

https://www.hostingportaal.nl/nieuws/page/2/

I want the slug to be:

https://www.hostingportaal.nl/nieuws/pagina/2/

Is it possible to change the slug with a hook or something? Would like to know how I can change this. Help would be very welcome.

Thanks, and keep up the good work. I really love Genesis!

Kind regards,

Joep

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to using Genesis, or any other particular theme. It's a more general WordPress issue.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/change-the-page-slug-in-pagination has a couple of solutions, the first of which is copied and amended here:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Page to Pagina
 * Description: Change <code>/page/</code> to <code>/pagina/</code>.
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz <info@toscho.de>
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 't5_page_to_pagina' ) ) {
    register_activation_hook(   __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
    add_action( 'init', 't5_page_to_pagina' );

    function t5_page_to_pagina() {
        $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->pagination_base = 'pagina';
    }

    function t5_flush_rewrite_on_init() {
        add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules', 11 );
    }
}
```